# replace 0.01 with the row maximum value from another columns

Tags: python, pandas

There is such dataframe df

```
    article   price1   price2   price3
0  A9911652     0.01     0.01  2980.31
1  A9911653  7041.33     0.01  2869.40
2  A9911654     0.01  9324.63     0.01
3  A9911659  4785.74     0.01  1622.78
4  A9911661  6067.27  6673.99     0.01
```

I'd like to replace the 0.01 values with the maximum value of the row, so it should look this way:

```
    article   price1   price2   price3
0  A9911652  2980.31  2980.31  2980.31
1  A9911653  7041.33  7041.33  2869.40
2  A9911654  9324.63  9324.63  9324.63
3  A9911659  4785.74  4785.74  1622.78
4  A9911661  6067.27  6673.99  6673.99
```

I tried the following:

```
    df.replace(0.01,df[['price3','price2','price1']].max(axis=1),inplace=True)
```

But it doesn't change anything. What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `axis=0` parameter:

```
df = df.mask(df == 0.01, df[['price3','price2','price1']].max(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
    article   price1   price2   price3
0  A9911652  2980.31  2980.31  2980.31
1  A9911653  7041.33  7041.33  2869.40
2  A9911654  9324.63  9324.63  9324.63
3  A9911659  4785.74  4785.74  1622.78
4  A9911661  6067.27  6673.99  6673.99
```

If want specify columns for set new values:

```
c =['price3','price2','price1']
df[c] = df[c].mask(df[c] == 0.01, df[c].max(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)

    article   price1   price2   price3
0  A9911652  2980.31  2980.31  2980.31
1  A9911653  7041.33  7041.33  2869.40
2  A9911654  9324.63  9324.63  9324.63
3  A9911659  4785.74  4785.74  1622.78
4  A9911661  6067.27  6673.99  6673.99
```